# C string dereference and then re-reference acting strangely?

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I have the following bit of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char *p = "abc";
  char c = *p;
  printf(&c);
  return 0;
}
```

Running, I get

```
[OP@localhost test]$ gcc ptr.c
[OP@localhost test]$ ./a.out 
a%QV[OP@localhost test]$
```

I was expecting it to just print "abc". Why does this happen?

Comment: `c` is a single character (containing only `'a'`), so `&c` will not be a null-terminated string.

Comment: The address of `c` (determined by `&c`) is not the same as the address of `"abc"` (which is the pointer stored in `p`).

Comment: @lurker Great, this is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 3):

`char c = *p;` this does a hard copy of the first letter in the string `"abc"`, nothing else.

Therefore you end up lying to `printf` and tell it that at the address of the single character `c`, it will find a whole, valid format string.

But it will only find the character `a` which is not a string at all, since there is no null terminator anywhere. So anything can happen, including a program crash or the program printing garbage.

Answer (score 0):

The format string is expected to be a NUL-terminated sequence of characters.

`printf(p)` works because

- `*(p+0)` is 61
- `*(p+1)` is 62
- `*(p+2)` is 63
- `*(p+3)` is 0

`printf(&c)` doesn't work because

- `*(&c+0)` is 61
- `*(&c+1)` is {Undefined behaviour to access}

Solution 1:

```
char *p = "abc";
char c = *p;
printf("%c". c);       // a
```

Solution 2:

```
char *p = "abc";
char *p2 = *p;         // Copies the pointer
printf(p2);            // abc
```

Solution 3:

```
char *p = "abc";
char *p2 = strdup(p);  // Copies the string (e.g. so you could modify it)
printf(p2);            // abc
free(p2);
```

---

Tip: Unless you can guarantee a lack of `%`, `printf(p)` is usually [wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection). Use `printf("%s", p)`.